# Motivation for forming a specific bound for a recursively defined sequence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Often, it is not easy to observe a specific bound for a recursively defined sequence.

The simplest method would be to write a finite number of terms and observe the pattern.

However, in many cases, this approach is not useful.

For example,

Suppose $c>0$ and $0<a<\frac{1}{c}$. Define the sequence $(x_{n})$ as follows,
$$x_{0}=a,\text{  } x_{n}=x_{n-1}(2-cx_{n-1}) \text{    for   }n=1,2,...$$

The original question is to prove that the sequence converges to $\frac{1}{c}$.

It was said that the first step is to show that $0<x_{n}<\frac{1}{c}$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$

My question:

How can we tell that the inequality holds without beforehand knowing it is true?

What is the motivation?

Any useful tricks i can use for this situation?

Any kind person can help me? i will be greatly grateful. Thanks

Comment: Definitely induction. The base case is given (i.e. we know $x_0=a<\frac{1}{c}$). Now assume $x_k<\frac{1}{c}$ and show $x_{k+1}<\frac{1}{c}$.

Comment: Yes,we can definitely show the inequality by induction. My question is, what is the inspiration behind showing the inequality? What makes you think of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean why choose $\frac{1}{c}$ as a bound for $x_n $, without knowing beforehand that this is a bound?

Comment: Yes! and also why choose 0 as a lower bound without knowing it before hand as well.

Comment: Well I would try these bounds out simply because $0<x_0<\frac{1}{c}$ is given, so this is a good place to start looking for a bound for all $x_n$. This does not guarantee that these bounds will work in general, but it is a good place to start.

Comment: Besides that, any clue that can be observed from the sequence?

Comment: Well, for the $\frac{1}{c}$ bound, one can easily observe that $x_{n+1}=2x_n-cx_n^2$. From this one could see that if $x_n <\frac{1}{c}$, then $x_{n+1}$ will be less than $\frac{1}{c}$ from appropriate cancellations. This provides motivation for induction. The motivation can often be difficult, so this just provides a good starting point, which happens to hold in this case.

Comment: From this one could see that if $x_{n}<\frac{1}{n}$, then $x_{n}$ will be less than $\frac{1}{c}$ from appropriate cancellations.

Can u show the cancellations please?

Comment: I just mean that $x_n<\frac{1}{c}\implies x_n^2<\frac{1}{c^2}\implies 2x_n-cx_n^2<\frac{2}{c}-c\frac{1}{c^2}=\frac{1}{c}$.

Comment: @Dave You do not know if $x_{n}$ is positive or negative, u cannot just assume the sign of the inequality when u square both sides of the inequality.

Comment: That's a good point, but one would also prove that $x_n>0$ as mentioned above. The motivation for this is similar to the other bound, in that the bound is given to hold for $x_0>0$, so this is a good place to start for a general bound.

Comment: @Dave i still feel guessing the bound without observations is not right. We should be able to observe a characteristic about the recursively defined sequence then guess the bound.

Comment: @Dave You may want to check your proof that $x_{n+1}<\frac1c$.  You used $x_n^2<\frac1{c^2}\implies-cx_n^2<-c\frac1{c^2}$, which is backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I check a calculator to see if the sequence is monotone (increasing or decreasing).  This is not a proof of course, but it does give you a good idea of what you want to prove.

Then, I assume it exists if it looks like it does or if it doesn't, then I prove it doesn't.  At this step, I substitute $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ to get

$$L=L(2-cL)$$

Solving this with the assumption that $L>0$ gives

$$L=\frac1c$$

Note that assuming $L>0$ is not a big problem since we can clearly see we should have $L>0$ in the calculator.  Likewise, we can see it should be monotone increasing.  Thus, putting two and two together, we want to prove the following:

$$\text{Verify this is monotone:}\quad x_{n+1}>x_n(>0)$$

$$\text{Show that it is bounded above:}\quad x_n<~?$$

Now, what should be our upper bound you ask?  For problems like this, it almost always works beautifully to set the upper bound we want to prove to be the limit itself.

$$x_n<\frac1c\tag1$$

Now, let's prove:

$$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=x_n(2-cx_n)\\(1)~&>x_n\left(2-c\frac1c\right)\\&=x_n(2-1)\\&=x_n\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ uses our assumed upper bound $x_n<\frac1c$.  Now we prove the upper bound without any assumptions to avoid paradoxes:

First, notice that

$$\left(\sqrt cx_n-\frac1{\sqrt c}\right)^2=cx_n^2-2x_n+\frac1c\tag2$$

It thus follows that

$$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=x_n(2-cx_n)\\&=2x_n-cx_n^2\\(2)~&=\frac1c-\left(\sqrt cx_n-\frac1{\sqrt c}\right)^2\\&<\frac1c\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.